# make drug to be in patient’s body

Tags: single-word-requests

What the words (verb and noun) are used in medicine to describe the process as a result of which drug appears in the patient's body?
I need the word that describes the process in general, without specifying the way (drug can be syringed into or eaten by patient, etc; it is not specified).

Suppose we want to describe a scheme for the action of some drug, like this:

1. Drug _______ (or “_______ the drug”).
2. Moving of the drug with bloodstream throughout the body.
3. Getting the drug to the liver.
4. Getting the drug into the liver cells.
5. Inhibition of the enzyme by the drug.

My question is referred to step 1 and it is how to say briefly about the process of getting, arriving, gaining the drug into the patient's body, in general, irrespectively of the way.

Before this process, the drug was, for example, on the table or in the nightstand.

After the process, the drug is in the body.

If a syringe was used in this process, I would say “Syringing the drug” (however, I don't know if it's correct). 
But I want to abstract away from whether a syringe or some other device is used in this process.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Are you looking for *take*: "take a pill", "take an intravenous injection", etc.? Please review the guidelines given [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for [single-word-requests].

Comment: Are you asking about a ***prescription*** (n) that is ***prescribed*** (v)?

Comment: Or maybe a ***dosage*** that is ***delivered***?

Comment: Drugs are *administered* and the process is called *administration*.

Comment: @Mick - Am I administering aspirin when I take one myself. I think of administering when someone gives it to someone else.

Comment: @Jim It is definitely not “prescription” and not “prescribe”.
I seem “delivery” may fit, but my level of English does not allow me to say definitely.
Maybe “enter(ing)”?

I have edited (added) my question, please look above.

Comment: @Jim *self-administering*

Answer (score 1):

Drug was “administered” to the patient.

Answer (score 1):

The process of getting drugs into a patients body by a qualified professional (e.g. doctor, nurse or vet) is known as *administration*, and the verb is *administer*. It is called *self-administration* if a non-medical person gives drugs to someone else (or an animal), or if you give drugs to yourself (i.e. take drugs).

Note that these are really medical usages. In everyday English, you simply *take* a drug (or *give* a drug to someone else).

> **administration** noun (GIVING) [ U ]
>
> the act of giving someone something:
>
> - There are strict controls on the administration of drugs.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/administration)

---

The following references are pretty random, but they show medical and scientific usages from reasonable sources.

[Wikipedia: Route of administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_of_administration)

[Self-administration of drugs in animals and humans as a model and an investigative tool](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2695138/)